# Compilation error when using isLeaf() method

Tags: java, swing, nodes, jtree, huffman-code

I'm trying to move around nodes and append them either a 0 or a 1 depending on their position, as I'm doing a Huffman compression test.

However, when trying to use the method `isLeaf()` which is from `javax.swing.tree`.

Here's the segment of the code that's giving me issues.

```
private static void createTestMap(
final Node node,
final String string,
final Map<Character, String> map)
{
    if(!node.isLeaf())
    {
       createTestMap(nodo.leftChild, string + "0", map);
       createTestMap(nodo.rightChild, string + '1', map);
    }
    else
    {
        map.put(node.test, string);
    }
}
```

With the node code on a different class.
On this one it's giving me an error:

```
cannot find symbol - method isLeaf()
```

I'm extremely new to Java and coding in general so I'm not quite sure what's missing, as I've seen this method being used in several programs related to Huffman compression through nodes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does a "Cannot find symbol" compilation error mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706216/what-does-a-cannot-find-symbol-compilation-error-mean)

Answer (score 1):

The [`isLeaf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultMutableTreeNode.html#isLeaf--) method is defined for a **sub-class** of **`TreeNode`**, specifically `DefaultMutableTreeNode`.

> I've seen this method being used in several programs

Always consult the Java Docs to **understand** random snippets of code from the internet.

Answer (score 1):

The only two `Node` classes in the JDK are `javax.xml.soap.Node` and `org.w3c.dom.Node`.

You should be using `javax.swing.tree.TreeNode` or indeed `javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode`.

Comment: I'm guessing that it's supposed to be a `Node`  class that's part of the project.